# Terminals freezing Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: gnome-terminal

I work with Ubuntu 20.04.1

I notice that sometimes the terminals freeze, I cannot switch between them. What is wrong?[image]

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV.

Comment: @waltinator, how can I check the amount of RAM?

Comment: `sudo lshw -C memory`, `sudo journalctl  -b 0` will show actual RAM, `free` will show available memory and swap.